# Diffrence between "for (elm <- myList) yield f(_)" and "myList map f(_)" in Scala

Tags: scala, functional-programming

Why does the different lines give different return values?

```
val tagIds = postData._1 map (TagTable.newTag(_))
// tagIds is defined as val tagIds: Array[Long]
```

and

```
val tagIds = for(tag <- postData._1) yield TagTable.newTag(_)
// tagIds is defined as val tagIds: Array[models.UnsavedTag => Long]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Due to a simple typing error:

```
val tagIds = for(tag <- postData._1) yield TagTable.newTag(tag)
                                                           ^^^
```

Comment: No that was not a typing error I assumed that _ and tag would mean the same in a one parameter expression.

Comment: Ah, not really, `TagTable.newTag(_)` is equivalent to `(x: models.UnsavedTag) => TagTable.newTag(x)`...

Answer (score 2):

```
val tagIds = postData._1 map (TagTable.newTag(_))
```

This line says take each item `tag` contained in the collection `postData._1` and call `TagTable.newTag(tag)`.  Then, `tagIds` is a collection containing all of the results of those calls.

```
val tagIds = for(tag <- postData._1) yield TagTable.newTag(_)
```

This line says for each item `tag` contained in the collection `postData._1`, return the function `TagTable.newTag(_)` (which is equivalent to the function `x => TagTable.newTag(x)`).  Then, `tagIds` is a collection containing all of those functions.

Basically, you aren't actually calling the function in the second version.  Change it to this:

```
val tagIds = for(tag <- postData._1) yield TagTable.newTag(tag)
```